# WCF: ZIP file generation

Tags: c#, wcf

I am uploading a file using a WCF service.

The client side code looks like this:

```
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endPointAddress = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(address);
IFileStreamService proxy = new FileStreamServiceClient("FileTransfer", endPointAddress);             
proxy.UploadFile(uploadReq);  //upload the file
```

Server side includes

```
public void UploadFile(FileUploadRequest uploadRequest)
{
    try
    {
        string targetFile = uploadRequest.getTargetFile();                
        Stream sourceStream = uploadRequest.FileByStream;
        Log("Going to read stream from client");

        using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            const int bufferSize = 65536; // 64K chunk
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                outfile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not doing any zipping at client side. But at the server side zip file is getting created like this

```
  temp_c7dfbfd7-3495-43b6-a0ec-e46153cef72a.zip
```

zip file is also corrupted. Can anybody point me to where things are going wrong?

Comment: Are the files the same size?  Is it just that, say, the last block is not being uploaded?